# Cannot install petsc4py on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: python-3.8, petsc

After successfully installing and testing PETSc I went ahead and tried to install petsc4py with:

```
$ sudo python3 -m pip install petsc4py
```

but got loads of errors. Here are the messages:

```
Collecting petsc4py
  Using cached petsc4py-3.16.1.tar.gz (2.3 MB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/
    Complete output (54 lines):
    running egg_info
    creating /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info/petsc4py.egg-info
    writing /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info/petsc4py.egg-info/PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info/petsc4py.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info/petsc4py.egg-info/requires.txt
    writing top-level names to /tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info/petsc4py.egg-info/top_level.txt
    writing manifest file '/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/pip-egg-info/petsc4py.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/setup.py", line 289, in <module>
        main()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/setup.py", line 286, in main
        run_setup()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/setup.py", line 135, in run_setup
        setup(packages     = ['petsc4py',
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 155, in setup
        return distutils.core.setup(**attrs)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 148, in setup
        return run_commands(dist)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/core.py", line 163, in run_commands
        dist.run_commands()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 967, in run_commands
        self.run_command(cmd)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/dist.py", line 986, in run_command
        cmd_obj.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 298, in run
        self.find_sources()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 305, in find_sources
        mm.run()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 540, in run
        self.add_defaults()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/command/egg_info.py", line 577, in add_defaults
        sdist.add_defaults(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/sdist.py", line 226, in add_defaults
        self._add_defaults_python()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/command/sdist.py", line 111, in _add_defaults_python
        build_py = self.get_finalized_command('build_py')
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 299, in get_finalized_command
        cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/command/build_py.py", line 29, in finalize_options
        orig.build_py.finalize_options(self)
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/command/build_py.py", line 43, in finalize_options
        self.set_undefined_options('build',
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 287, in set_undefined_options
        src_cmd_obj.ensure_finalized()
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/setuptools/_distutils/cmd.py", line 107, in ensure_finalized
        self.finalize_options()
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/conf/baseconf.py", line 411, in finalize_options
        self.petsc_dir  = config.get_petsc_dir(self.petsc_dir)
      File "/tmp/pip-install-yg5szcfl/petsc4py/conf/baseconf.py", line 349, in get_petsc_dir
        petsc_dir = petsc.get_petsc_dir()
    AttributeError: module 'petsc' has no attribute 'get_petsc_dir'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

There are so many error messages that I have no idea where from I should start. Any help? The installation should be straightforward, I don't know what's going on. Trying to fix the package (or setup.py thereof) manually is futile. I'm using Python 3.8.10.

Any hints will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution I found to solve this issue in one of my Dockerfile is simply to use `apt-get install -y python3-petsc4py-complex`.

(If you want/have the petsc real version, use `apt-get install -y python3-petsc4py-real` instead).

From those who are interested, the same idea can be applied for slepc with `apt-get install -y python3-slepc4py-complex`.

Feel free to tell me if it works ! If not, I will try on a new Dockerfile to solve this.